# Tomcat: Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm implementing a REST Api which need download files from Amazon S3. 
When I call the api, it gives me the exception:

`com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.`

Then I run the same method API called, it succeeded. I'm using tomcat 9.0.2, my guess is the default credential directory ~/.aws/credential is different for tomcat application.

So I checked $CATALINA_HOME, which is /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.2 and I copied the credentials there, still not working.

First time asking questions here, I hope that I expressed my issue clearly. Thanks for any help from anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The home directory `~` depends on the user running the Tomcat server, so if Tomcat is running as the root user, for example, you'd need to place the credentials in `/root/.aws/credentials`.

Depending on the Tomcat version, you can usually find the default user in `/etc/default/tomcat7`. It would appear as something like:

```
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7
```

In that case, the home directory would be `/home/tomcat7`, and thus the credentials would go in `/home/tomcat7/.aws/credentials`.